# c# string to sqlstring losing format

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR function that receives a SQLString, and I am converting the Sql string to a c# string with `.ToString()`, then after some computing I want to return a sring that contains **doubles**

```
   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
   public static string FuncCS(SqlString SQLstr){
   string CSstr = SQLstr.ToString();

     /*DO SOME STUFF*/
    for (int j = 0; j < S.ColumnCount; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < S.RowCount; i++){
            CSstr += S[i, j].ToString("F5") + " ,  \t"; 
        }           
    }
  }
```

Then in SQL I receive a string but the doubles lose their **decimal point** and is substituted by a misplaced comma:

RESULT:

```
149,50625 0,00000 0,00000 0,00000 0,00000 69,06880 0,00000 0,00000 0,00000 0,00000 31,61588 0,00000 0,00000 0,00000 0,00000 8,82157
```

WHAT IS NEEDED:

```
14.9506245839579,0,0,0,0,6.90687968992126,0,0,0,0,3.16158756810842,0,0,0,0,0.88215732592823
```

What do I change in the for loop?

Comment: FYI, you don't have "a CLR". You have a ["CLR user-defined function"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131077.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine "culture"; try using `ToString("F5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Also - look at `StringBuilder` for building a string in a loop.

Comment: I am getting incorrect results, After doing what you suggested I get: `149.50625, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 69.06880, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 31.61588, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 8.82157, `  instead `14.9506245839579,0,0,0,0,6.90687968992126,0,0,0,0,3.16158756810842,0,0,0,0,0.88215732592823` is like it would be multiplying by ten each double

Comment: @cMinor well, what are the inputs here? Is the first number 14(ish) or 149(ish)?

Comment: @cMinor also, if you didn't want fixed precision, why did you choose F5?

Comment: the input would be `14.9506245839579`, but getting `149.50625`

Comment: @cMinor probably `"R"` (round-trip). Alternatively, `"G"` (general)

Comment: @cMinor are you very sure that 14.9 is coming out as 149? Also, try with an alternative format specifier, but  that sounds... unlikely.

Comment: well I am sure that the result is 14.9 as I print it in console, the result I see in SQL is 149, let me try with R

Comment: well, The precition is better with `R` but keep getting 149 instead 14.9 with `G` is the same but is has less precistion

Comment: Would be a good idea use  `.ToString(Settings.DecimalFormat)`

Answer (score 1):

What is the result if you just use

```
CSstr += S[i, j] + " ,  \t";
```

?

Comment: the result is: `149,506245839579 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   69,0687968992126 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   31,6158756810842 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   0 ,   8,82157325928232 ,   `

Comment: try `double d = Double.Parse(S[i, j], new CultureInfo("de-DE"));` Question: What culture do you have in your db and client? Are you sure the values are stored correctly in the db?